# How to move all old files from Downloads to the trash with one or more terminal commands?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, spotlight, trash

I already found the command with which I can select all the files and directories that I do **not** want to send to trash. That command looks like this:

`find ~/Downloads -newerat "2 months ago" -or -newerct "2 months ago" -or -newermt "2 months ago" | grep -E "^$HOME/Downloads/[^/]+$"`

So the `find` part of the command selects every file and folder which has either been added, created, or modified in the last two months. And then the `grep` portion of the command filters the list so that it only contains the top-level files and folders.

So that means for example that:

```
~/Downloads/SomeMovie/SomeMovie.mp4
~/Downloads/SomeMovie/SomeMovie.srt
```

Will just be filtered down to:

```
~/Downloads/SomeMovie
```

Now again, this is the list of files and folders I **do not** want to send to trash. For some reason I found this query easier to compute in my head. Now I'm wondering how I can best get the inverse of this list?

And by the inverse of this list I mean, if `find` starts selecting files and folders that have *not* been added, created, or modified in the last two months, I want to make sure that if any sub-tree contains even just *one* file that *was* added, created, or modified in the last two months, that then that entire sub-tree will be excluded from the search results.

You know what I mean? That's the part that I didn't know how to express that in a query.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://superuser.com/questions/1742849/how-to-move-all-old-files-from-downloads-to-the-trash-with-one-or-more-terminal

Comment: I find [Hazel](https://www.noodlesoft.com/) an easier way to do this